# How to store primary key in front end object Mongo DB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I am working on a web app using meteor, angularJS, and mongodb. I am creating a messaging feature that allows users to add comments to videos. Up until now, I have only implemented the creation and display of messages to my view. Users can create messages that are then saved to the mongo database and retrieved whenever the page is loaded.

However, now I want to add the functionality to delete messages. As of now, I am just retrieving the comment string from the db and displaying it in an ng-repeat directive. I want to be able to click on the displayed message (using a button on the front end) and delete it both from the UI and the db. Right now, I have the code to retrieve the object the message is stored in on the front end and to delete it from the view.

But, I have no way of getting the primary key to this message in the database. As a result, the message never gets deleted from the database and it keeps reappearing on page reload.

I don't know too much about security or mongo db, so, what is the safest way to store / retrieve primary keys on the front end? The goal is to be able to click on a message in the DOM, delete it from the DOM, and have the primary key so that it can also be delete from the database.

Comment: So, are you planning to store the keys on frontend... with what purpose? What is what you actually are planning to do. You talk here about some different things. What's your question exactly?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. Basically, I don't know how to get the primary key for a message when I click on it in the front end. Thus, I don't know how to delete it from the database

Comment: If you post some code of what you have done so far, I could point you on the right direction better. So far I can recommend you: load the comments from backend with two values (at least), text(or whatever you call it) and the comment id. Then implement a function(frontend) which calls a service (backend) which deletes a comment given its id (Also when the service callback return ok, delete the comment from backend). When page loads again the comment won't be there.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of storing the id along with the comment string in a front end object. I believe that is what you are suggesting? I just wanted to make sure this wouldn't be a serious security issue

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I suggested.About your security concern..it depends on how you store that data. If you save it to localstorage as a stringified json as `"["comments":"{label:"bla", "id": 3}"]"`, that would be a security risk! since if your local storage is compromised your comment are too. But if you save that data in _js_ vars such `_c = [{id:3, l:'bla'}], and even with your js minified..mmm...it would be worth to analyze if that info is in risk. Anyway, when talking about security it is worth mentioning that we always look for a balance between "value" <--> "cost-of-breaking-it-down"

Comment: Thanks for the info. Ill keep looking into it, but the data would just be an id for a comment. Its not necessarily sensitive or protected information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Angular so I'm not sure how exactly it handles this, but in Blaze whenever you use `{{#each}}`, the context of `this` is unique for each repeated object from your DB.

So in Blaze, if you are iterating over an array of objects (comments), in your comment template you assign an event listener to the `delete` button that calls a `meteor method` that uses `this._id` as the primary key. Then when you click the delete button, it passes the object's ID to the method. That's how the DB knows which object to delete.

Angular will have a similar system. [Here's a link to the Meteor Angular tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/update-and-remove) where they are deleting items from an `ng-repeat` block. It should help!